# HTML + JavaScript: How to change image source on li hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a ul with 5 li's inside it, and the ul is in a span of 6:

```
<div class="coffee-span-6 recent-news-list">
 <ul class="unorder-list news-item-list">
  <li class="news-item"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
  <li class="news-item"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
  <li class="news-item"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
  <li class="news-item"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
  <li class="news-item"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

And then another span 6 with one image:

```
<div class="coffee-span-6 recent-news-col">
    <img id="image" src="http://lorempixel.com/460/200/abstract/1"
</div>
```

I want it to be like, when I hover over the first li, it changes the image source, then on hover out, it reverts back to its original image. I tried this:

```
<li class="news-item" onmouseover="changeImage();" onmouseout="revertImage();"> <-- this is first li
```

And for the script:

```
<script>
  function changeImage(){
            document.getElementById("image").src="http://lorempixel.com/460/200/abstract/2";
} 
function revertImage(){
        document.getElementById("image").src="http://lorempixel.com/460/200/abstract/1";
}
```

I mean, it works, but if I implement the onmouseover and onmouseout on the other li's:

```
<li class="news-item" onmouseover="changeImage();" onmouseout="revertImage();">
<li class="news-item" onmouseover="changeImage();" onmouseout="revertImage();">
<li class="news-item" onmouseover="changeImage();" onmouseout="revertImage();">
<li class="news-item" onmouseover="changeImage();" onmouseout="revertImage();">
<li class="news-item" onmouseover="changeImage();" onmouseout="revertImage();">
```

and I want to make the image change ***depending*** on the li, how do I do that?? I don't think making each li have a different method is very efficient...Is there a way to do this with more JavaScript or maybe JQuery?

Comment: if the `li` have an unique id or other element you could pass `this` to `changeImage` and then change Image would change depending on the parameter

Comment: your `<image />` is incorrectly formed, end tag is missing

Comment: @Zeratops it works either way, both are valid. Also, it's `<img>` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the url of the images by parameter to your functions:

```
<li class="news-item" onmouseover="changeImage('http://foo.com/img1.jpg');" onmouseout="revertImage('http://foo.com/imgBase.jpg');">
<li class="news-item" onmouseover="changeImage('http://foo.com/img2.jpg');" onmouseout="revertImage('http://foo.com/imgBase.jpg');">
<li class="news-item" onmouseover="changeImage('http://foo.com/img3.jpg');" onmouseout="revertImage('http://foo.com/imgBase.jpg');">
<li class="news-item" onmouseover="changeImage('http://foo.com/img4.jpg');" onmouseout="revertImage('http://foo.com/imgBase.jpg');">
<li class="news-item" onmouseover="changeImage('http://foo.com/img5.jpg');" onmouseout="revertImage('http://foo.com/imgBase.jpg');">
```

And then:

```
  function changeImage(imgSrc){
      document.getElementById("image").src=imgSrc;
  } 
  function revertImage(imgSrc){ 
      document.getElementById("image").src=imgSrc;
  }
```

Comment: THANK YOU IT WORKED! But with one small problem: 
`document.getElementByid('image')`
Single quote, not double quote.

Answer (score 0):

You may think of adding a `data-` attribute to the `li`s this way:

```
<div class="coffee-span-6 recent-news-list">
  <ul class="unorder-list news-item-list">
    <li class="news-item" data-item="1"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
    <li class="news-item" data-item="2"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
    <li class="news-item" data-item="3"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
    <li class="news-item" data-item="4"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
    <li class="news-item" data-item="5"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And you can control the image source by using this:

```
$(function () {
    // Grab all the news items.
    $(".news-item").hover(function () {
        // Replace with new image.
        $("#img-" + $(this).data("item")).data("src", $("#img-" + $(this).data("item")).attr("src"));
        $("#img-" + $(this).data("item")).attr("src", "new-" + $(this).data("item") + ".png");
    }, function () {
        // Reset the old image.
        $("#img-" + $(this).data("item")).attr("src", $("#img-" + $(this).data("item")).data("src"));
    });
});
```

That above code works for all the images like:

```
<img src="" alt="" id="img-1" />
<img src="" alt="" id="img-2" />
<img src="" alt="" id="img-3" />
<img src="" alt="" id="img-4" />
<img src="" alt="" id="img-5" />
```

**And with One Image:**

```
$(function () {
    // Grab all the news items.
    $(".news-item").hover(function () {
        // Replace with new image.
        $("#image").data("src", $("#image").attr("src"));
        $("#image").attr("src", "new-" + $(this).data("item") + ".png");
    }, function () {
        // Reset the old image.
        $("#image").attr("src", $("#image").data("src"));
    });
});
```

Hope you can take this as a starting point to do your stuff.

Comment: Sorry, I think it's a little too long and complicated, but when I have more problems, I'll refer to this.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why not css?

```
a {
    background-image:url('myimage.jpg');
  }

a:hover {
    background-image:url('myotherimage.jpg');
}
```

If you need to keep this inside the html file, then use inline styling (not the best route).

Comment: Then how do you change it back to the original image? And also, I don't want the `a` to have a background image, I want to change another image's source.